# Access grouped data items with @Html.DisplayFor

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a view, where the list of the viewmodel is grouped by useraccounts.
I want to display the userrole of the user, before I use the foreach loop for each item in the group, but I haven't figured out, how I can display the string set with the Display Name tag.

This is the code of the view

```
@if (Model.bookings.Any())
                    {
                        @foreach (var group in Model.bookings.GroupBy(g => g.driver.userAccount))
                        {
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th></th>
                                <th>
                                   @group.First().driver.userrole: @group.Key
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                           @foreach (var item in group)
                           {
                             <tr>
                                 <td>
                                 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID)
                                 </td>
```

`@group.First().driver.userrole: @group.Key` shows me the 'right' value of the enumeration, but not the display name.
`@Html.DisplayFor(group.First() => group.First().userrole)` seems to be the wrong syntax.

This is how I use the tag in my enumeration:

```
[Display(Name = "Employee")]
employee = 2
```

Comment: Yes, that's a wrong syntax. Try if `@Html.DisplayFor(g => group.First().userrole)` works?

Comment: Kindly accept the answer below by using the tick mark. Thank you.

Comment: Done! sorry, pretty new to stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for your `DisplayFor` is incorrect. Please use `@Html.DisplayFor(g => group.First().userrole)`

Please check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions) for a guide on how to use C# lambda expressions.